# Divide a ConstraintLayout in sub-parts with a different background

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

This is a constraint layout *containing four constraint layouts* in which I will put various Views such as buttons and the like.

[image]

Is there a way to tint the background color of separate areas of a constraint layout without the need to nest more layouts into the parent one?

Comment: what about applying a drawable as background?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with this snippet - 
Change background color as you want.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_ver"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".5" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_hor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".5" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/topLeft"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:background="#E02222"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline_hor"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="h,1:1"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".5"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline_ver" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/topRight"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:background="#411010"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline_hor"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="h,1:1"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/guideline_ver" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/bottomLeft"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:background="#165B92"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="h,1:1"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".5"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline_ver"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline_hor" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/bottomRight"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:background="#680C5F"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="h,1:1"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/guideline_ver"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline_hor" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Output will be look like below -

[image]

Comment: great, design XML style is using constraint layout is made easier and simpler